# Prediciting next numbers in a .Net random sequence

Tags: c#, .net, random

What I am trying to do is to predict the next number in a series of integers generated by `System.Random` from an existing sequence of 56+ random integers.

I know that `System.Random` uses the subtractive algorithm from  D. E. Knuth's book and that given the last 55 integers, the next integer in the sequence will be:

```
seq[n] = (seq[n-55] - seq[n-24]) % m
```

So I tried to populate a random list and find `m` with brute force.

```
var rnd = new Random();
var list = new List<int>();
for(var i=0; i< 56; i++)
    list.Add(rnd.Next());

var n1 = list[0];
var n2 = list[31];
var n = list[55];

Console.WriteLine("{0} = ({1} - {2}) % m", n, n1, n2);
for(var i = 1; i< int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    if (n == (n1 - n2) % i)
        Console.WriteLine("m = {0}", i);
}
```

It did not work. I then noticed an apparent [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug) in `System.Random` implementation where they used 34 instead of 24. I tried that also, again with no luck.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong in here.

Comment: "...based on a **modified** version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm..." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to replicate what `System.Random` currently does, I'd recommend looking at the [source code itself](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,dec894a7e816e665).

From a quick glance at that code, it seems like the closest thing to your m value is MBIG (`int.MaxValue`). Each resulting random value is bounded between 0 and MBIG exclusive:

int retVal;
          int locINext = inext;
          int locINextp = inextp;

```
      if (++locINext >=56) locINext=1;
      if (++locINextp>= 56) locINextp = 1;

      retVal = SeedArray[locINext]-SeedArray[locINextp];

      if (retVal == MBIG) retVal--;          
      if (retVal<0) retVal+=MBIG;

      SeedArray[locINext]=retVal;

      inext = locINext;
      inextp = locINextp;

      return retVal;
```